# Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ containing all the $m \times n$ matrices ,show that the $\text{dim}(V)=mn$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, kronecker-delta

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ containing all the $m \times n$ matrices ,show that  $\text{dim}(V)=mn$.

---

Define a family of matrices by $M_{i,j}=(m_{rq})=(\delta_{ri}\delta_{jq})\in \mathbb F^{m \times n}$

Take an arbitrary element $A \in V$ ,it's true to claim that $$A=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i,j}M_{i,j}$$

Besides the set $\left \{M_{i,j} \mid1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n\right\}$ is a linearly independent set since if for some $\lambda_{i,j} \in\mathbb F$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{i,j}M_{i,j}=0$$

Then the LHS is indeed a $m \times n$ matrix with the entry placed in the $i$th row and the $j$ th column equal to $\lambda _{i,j}$ which follows that all such scalars are zero,and hence the set is a lineary independent set.

Based on the definition of a basis it implies that $\left \{M_{i,j} \mid1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n\right\}$ is a linearly independent set sppaning $V$ and so form a basis of $V$,so the dimension of $V$ is determined by its basis which contains $mn$ elements.

---

---

The proof is the one that I've learned before and changed it a bit to make the proof easier to follow,but I'm not sure if the representation $M_{i,j}=(m_{rq})=(\delta_{ri}\delta_{jq})$ is true (this is what I've added to the original proof with some extra explanations).

It would be appreciated if someone checks that and if it's possible make the proof more
precise (if it's not as much as it can be ).

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: I have grown quite fond of Einstein summation notation recently and I don't believe this can get much simpler. A minor thing is that we don't usually put a coma between the row and column indices like $a_{i,j}.$ The convention is just $a_{ij},$ even for matrices induced by an entry like $M_{ij}$

Comment: @  dezdichado ,Yes that's right,after seeting a couple of Wiki's page I figured out that my notation (using the comma) is not common,besdies what do you think about the whole proof? Can it be simpler (and if it's needed) more accurate?

Comment: The proof is fine; one thing you should note is that it is not necessary to always state things in terms of "formulas". Also, just because one uses formulas, I don't think that makes it more precise. Sometimes words are just as effective (and acceptable), so saying something like "let $M_{ij}$ the $m\times n$ matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$ and all other entries $0$" is perfectly fine, and I think this is much easier to read (but again, overall the proof is fine).